# Monty Hall problem but for 1000 doors (by Bayes theorem)

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, bayes-theorem, monty-hall

I know how to prove this statement by Bayes theorem when we have 3 doors with one car. But is it possible to solve this problem using Bayes theorem for 1000 doors?

In case with 3 doors I considered 4 events: $A, B, C$ are such events: car is in the 1st, the 2nd and the 3rd doors respectively. $OB$ is event that door number 2 will be revealed. So, applying Bayes formula we get

$$P(C\mid OB) = \frac{P(OB\mid C) \cdot P(C)}{P(OB)}$$

where $P(OB\mid C)$ is probability that we are looking for (do we have to change dor that we chose at first ($A$) to another ($C$), to make it clear let us imagine that if it is possible B will always be revealed (if there is no prize). $P(OB\mid C)$ is probability that door 2 will be revealed considering the fact that the actual prize is in third door. $P(C)$ is probability that prize is in the 3rd door. And P(OB) is probability that door number 2 will be revealed.

*If you are able to prove that we should change door only without using Bayes theorem, that would be helpful too

Comment: If Monty Hall always shows you a goat, and you always switch, you will win precisely when the first door you picked concealed a goat: $2/3$ of the time.  If you don't switch you'll win if and only if you originally picked the car: $1/3$ of the time.

Comment: @saulspatz Yes, in case there are 3 doors, but what about 1000?

Comment: What is the question if there are $1000$ doors?

Comment: @saulspatz It is pretty much the same. You are choosing one door. After that Monty Hall reveals you one of 999 doors which are left (he always reveals door with goat). So, what probability of win do we get if we change door. My hypothesis is 999/998000

Comment: Is there a car behind only one door?

Comment: I agree with $999/998,000$ if three's only one car.  The probability that we didn't pick the car the first time is $999/1000$ and it's equally likely to be behind any of the remaining $998$ doors.

Comment: With more than 26 doors, you won't have enough letters to label the events.